# What is the best LLM that can be used on a single GPU?

Tags: language-model

I am interested in the best/state-of-the-art Large Language model that can be used in a single GPU.
I read that Falcon 7B is state-of-the-art. Is there anything better? Any data that show the pros/cons of LLMs would be helpful.
Thanks